# Is there a way to prevent a dimension from being filtered by another dimension in dc.js?

Tags: dc.js

Let's say I have a dataset with three dimensions: X, A, and B.

I want to prevent X from being filtered by brush events in A or B. However, I still want to filter A or B by any dimension, including X.

That is,

```
X -> A
X -> B
A <-> B
```

Is there a way to make X one-way or read-only?

Comment: Is it safe to pass dc.js a real dimension and a fake group that is not in any way connected to the dimension? The fake group will contain all the data.

Comment: Sure, you could use a fake group. It's perfectly safe for the dimension and group to be disconnected, as long as the behavior is what you expect.

Comment: Probably pre-calculating the values and using fake groups is the way to go. But if you need it to be more dynamic, you could use the data lifecycle information available in group accessors as of Crossfilter 1.4 to ignore filter events in groups you define on X.

Comment: Thanks! Crossfilter 1.4 is fresh out of the oven. I will check that out.